# Understanding equatiomatic output

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I have fit a `lmer` model as follows:

```r
m1 <- lmer(spad ~ farm * treat * stage + (1|farm:block) + 
                  (1|farm:block:treat), data = dt) 
# random effects are the blocks within farms, and treatments within 
# blocks within farms.
```

There are 5 farms, 2 treat, and 3 stages.
Using the `equatiomatic` package allows be to write out a physical model:

```
equatiomatic::extract_eq(m1, use_coefs = FALSE)
```

\begin{aligned}
  \text{spad}_{i} & \sim \mathcal{N} (\mu, \sigma^2) \\
  \mu &= \alpha_{j[i],k[i]} + \beta_{1}(\text{farm}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{2}(\text{farm}_{\text{3}}) + \beta_{3}(\text{farm}_{\text{4}}) + \beta_{4}(\text{farm}_{\text{5}}) + \beta_{5}(\text{treat}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{6}(\text{stage}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{7}(\text{stage}_{\text{3}}) \\
  & \quad + \beta_{8}(\text{farm}_{\text{2}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{9}(\text{farm}_{\text{3}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{10}(\text{farm}_{\text{4}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{11}(\text{farm}_{\text{5}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) \\
  & \quad + \beta_{12}(\text{farm}_{\text{2}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{13}(\text{farm}_{\text{3}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{14}(\text{farm}_{\text{4}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{15}(\text{farm}_{\text{5}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{2}}) \\
  & \quad + \beta_{16}(\text{farm}_{\text{2}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{3}}) + \beta_{17}(\text{farm}_{\text{3}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{3}}) + \beta_{18}(\text{farm}_{\text{4}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{3}}) + \beta_{19}(\text{farm}_{\text{5}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{3}}) \\
  & \quad + \beta_{20}(\text{stage}_{\text{2}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{21}(\text{stage}_{\text{3}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{22}(\text{farm}_{\text{2}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{2}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) \\
  & \quad + \beta_{23}(\text{farm}_{\text{3}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{2}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{24}(\text{farm}_{\text{4}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{2}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{25}(\text{farm}_{\text{5}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{2}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) \\
  & \quad + \beta_{26}(\text{farm}_{\text{2}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{3}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{27}(\text{farm}_{\text{3}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{3}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) + \beta_{28}(\text{farm}_{\text{4}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{3}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) \\
  & \quad + \beta_{29}(\text{farm}_{\text{5}} \times \text{stage}_{\text{3}} \times \text{treat}_{\text{2}}) \\
  \alpha_{j} & \sim \mathcal{N} (\mu_{\alpha_{j}}, \sigma^2_{\alpha_{j}}), \text{ for farm:block:treat } j = 1, \dots, J \\
  \alpha_{k} & \sim \mathcal{N} (\mu_{\alpha_{k}}, \sigma^2_{\alpha_{k}}), \text{ for farm:block } k = 1, \dots, K
\end{aligned}

My question is:

**1. How should I write this model as linear combinations of the fixed effects and random effects, rather than following the Gelman and Hill 2006 notations?**

**2. Also I don't understand the subscript notations for the grand intercept, and why are the random effects being shown separately?**

Comment: What is `spad` here?

Comment: spad is the response.

Comment: Yes I mean what does spad measure.

Comment: Sorry-- it measures the greenness of the leaf. The response is a continous random variable.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately I'm busy at the moment so I can't supply an answer, but I'll briefly say that the notation is different to emphasize different points. For example, the $a$ notations at the bottom indicate the random intercepts (adjustments to the conditional mean) based on each grouping. If we put all of the notation into one linear equation, we sort of lose this information in the process (neither notation is *more correct*, just depends on the use case).